# Step motor intermediate position

Tags: stepper-motor, control

Is it possible to change the position of arrow to be a little more to upper winding or right winding? If we supply different values of voltage to two winding what will happen to arrow?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It will tend to move to an angle of arctan(V1/V2).